# How to install JDK 7u25 & NetBeans IDE 7.3.1 on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, netbeans, jdk

I have downloaded jdk-7u25-nb-7_3_1-linux-x64.sh and netbeans-7.3.1-linux.sh.

I installed JDK (which is bundle with NetBeans Base IDE) using

```
sudo sh jdk-7u25-nb-7_3_1-linux-x64.sh
```

I chose the installation folder to /opt/jdk_xxx/ and /opt/netbeans_xxx/ (I really wish not to install the program to the home directory), after the installation I don't see any shortcut to lunch the NetBeans IDE.

I also tried to install NetBeans IDE (Full Package) using

```
sudo sh jdk-7u25-nb-7_3_1-linux-x64.sh
```

But after the installation I still don't see the shortcut of the program, I also don't know how to create the shortcut by myself.

What to do next? or Have I done anything wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try look under menu?

Comment: @nickanor, I did but it's not there.

Answer (score 1):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=NetBeans IDE 7.3
Comment=The Smarter Way to Code
Exec=/bin/sh "path to your netbeans installation"  e.g(/opt/netbeans-7.3/bin/netbeans)
Icon=/opt/netbeans-7.3/nb/netbeans.png
Categories=Application;Development;Java;IDE;Programming;DeveloperTools;
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=0
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Save this file as `netbean<version code>.desktop`. Then save to `/home/user/.local/share/applications` directory